# how to loop and print out button class

Tags: plsql

I currently print out list of sections in table cells so will appear as links. 
Here is code:

```
.....
FOR i in 1 .. l_loop_count LOOP
-- Print end of row every 3 cells
IF (i > 1) and (mod(i,3) = 1) THEN
 print_out('"</tr><tr>" +');
END IF;
-- Print a blank cell if out of sections
IF i > g_sections.count THEN
  print_out('"<td></td>" +');
.....
```

What I would like to do is replace the links to be buttons. So all the sections name are inside buttons instead of links.
So was thinking I would need to change following line of code to print out a button using the button CSS but does not work.

```
print_out('"</tr><tr>" +');
```

to

```
print_out('"</tr><button class=\"btn\"></button><tr>" +');
```

In output, I still see the rows/cells with the links and now see a button on top of it with no text.

My whole code is too big to give out so hope the small titbit helps explain what I have.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question related to Oracle Application Express? If yes, you can use its tools for generating HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're inserting empty buttons between each table row. If i got you right, you want to insert Buttons **instead** of links.

So you need to add the `class="btn"`to your `<a>` tag to look like so: `<a class=\"btn\">` (assuming you're using Twitter Bootstrap or some other css that provides the btn class for `<a>` tags)

Can you please share the relevant code inserting the `<a>` tag?

---

edit:

### Try replacing

```
…

-- Print Section name
print_out('"<td><a href=\"javascript:;\" OnClick=\"displaySection(''TOC'',''' || to_char(i) || ''')\">' ||       
g_sections(i).name || '</a> " +');

…
```

### With

```
…

-- Print Section name
print_out('"<td><a class=\"btn\" href=\"javascript:;\" OnClick=\"displaySection(''TOC'',''' || to_char(i) || ''')\">' ||       
g_sections(i).name || '</a> " +');

…
```

Comment: Thanks josepp for your answer.

Here is my code with the a tag

Comment: Have you tried replacing `<a href…` with `<a class=\"btn\" href=…`

Comment: @AMRobert i have updated my answer to match your more verbose code

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN

-- Script tag, assign old content to var, reassign old content and new stuff
print_out('
<script type="text/javascript">
var auxs;
auxs = document.getElementById("toccontent").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("toccontent").innerHTML = auxs +
"<table width=\"100%\"><tr>" +');
-- Dont want less than 3 table cells per row so force to loop in multiples of 3
IF mod(g_sections.count,3) = 0 THEN
l_loop_count := g_sections.count;
ELSE
l_loop_count := g_sections.count + 3 - mod(g_sections.count,3);
END IF;
-- Loop through sections and generate HTML
FOR i in 1 .. l_loop_count LOOP
-- Print end of row every 3 cells
IF (i > 1) and (mod(i,3) = 1) THEN
 -- print_out('"</tr><tr>" +');
 print_out('"</tr><button class=\"btn\"></button><tr>" +');
END IF;
-- Print a blank cell if out of sections
IF i > g_sections.count THEN
  print_out('"<td></td>" +');
ELSE
  -- Add to counts
  l_cnt_err := l_cnt_err + g_sections(i).error_count;
  l_cnt_warn := l_cnt_warn + g_sections(i).warn_count;
  l_cnt_succ := l_cnt_succ + g_sections(i).success_count;
  -- Print Section name
  print_out('"<td><a href=\"javascript:;\" OnClick=\"displaySection(''TOC'',''' || to_char(i) || ''')\">' ||       
    g_sections(i).name || '</a> " +');
  -- Print if section in error or warning
  IF g_sections(i).result ='E' THEN 
  print_out('"<img class=\"error_ico\">" +');
    l_action_req := true;
  ELSIF g_sections(i).result ='W' THEN
    print_out('"<img class=\"warn_ico\">" +');
    l_action_req := true;
  END IF;
  -- Print end of cell
  print_out('"</td>" +');
END IF;
```

END LOOP;
  -- End the table
  print_out('"" +');
  print_out('"";');
  -- End
  print_out('');